# How to create a read-only backup user for PostgreSQL that does not fail when restoring

Tags: postgresql

I've been trying for a few days to create a read-only user that can only be backed up in my PostgreSQL database. The method I use to call pg_dump is a .bat file, below is the example below, how I'm going to implement it in my application.

```
cxMemo1.Clear;
cxMemo1.Lines.Add('@Echo off ');
cxMemo1.Lines.Add('set PGUSER=backup');
cxMemo1.Lines.Add('set PGPASSWORD=backup');
cxMemo1.Lines.Add('c:');
cxMemo1.Lines.Add('cd C:\Program Files (x86)\PostgreSQL\10\bin\ ');
cxMemo1.Lines.Add('@echo "Loading..." ');
cxMemo1.Lines.Add('pg_dump.exe -h localhost -F custom -p 5432  -f ' +Path+ ' BDFOCOG');

cxMemo1.Lines.SaveToFile(ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName) +'backup.bat');
ShellExecute(Application.Handle, nil, PChar('backup.bat'), nil, nil, SW_HIDE);
```

in image 1 I tried to do a restore after doing a backup with a postgres superuser that is read-only, but the data was created and this error occurred.

[Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tLnPn.png)

How can I resolve this issue to do a clean restore from a backup of my database?

Edit 1 - Image 2 shows the error that occurred when I did the restore using pg_restore, with the backup user that has the default_transection_read_only property set to true, the errors point to when the database will restore the foreign keys and among other changes.

[Image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c5liQ.png)

Edit 2 - It is worth noting that the data is transferred successfully, all of them and the bank is working normally apparently, my fear is that it may have corrupted some data, because the restoration has not occurred successfully according to PostgreSql and pg_restore.

Comment: You should post text as text, not as images of text.

Comment: You are using a buggy version of pgAdmin4, which fails to relay error messages to you.  The big empty box in image2 should have an error message in it.  Upgrade to a less-broken version of pgAdmin4, or better yet just use the command line program directly.

Comment: You are calling pg_dump with `-U`, which overrides the PGUSER variable you went out of your way to set a few lines up.

Comment: I added the written code and removed the -U Postgres code you told me about, about the pgAdmin4 version, I'm using 4.29 x86. I will do the restore through pg_restore to show the error that appears.